# What's the peer review queue as opposed to the edit suggestion queue?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Is that the same one?

Does the peer review queue refer to a question or an answer's versions, and the edit suggestion queue refer to the all site's edit suggestion?

If not, then what is the difference?

Comment: where are you seeing these terms? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Jeff It looks like [the faq-proposed question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work) uses both terminology. The [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) seems to prefer "edit suggestion".

Comment: Jeff, I saw it in your blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/ in this page, you mentioned the suggest edit queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are the same thing. The feature which allows low-rep users to make edits is known by the two names *peer review* (which is more conceptual in nature) and *edit suggestions*. The queue is the feature that allows 10k users to see all pending edit suggestions.